# How to pass parameters to a Blueprint function called from C++?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I have found this piece of code showing how to call a blueprint function from C++:

```
 UFUnction* Func = Obj->GetClass()->FindFunction(FName("FuncName"));
 if(Func == nullptr){return;}
 
 FStructOnScope FuncParam(Func);
 UProperty* ReturnProp = nullptr;
 
 for (TFieldIterator<UProperty> It(Func); It; ++It)
    {
     UProperty* Prop = *It;
     if (Prop->HasAnyPropertyFlags(CPF_ReturnParm))
     {
         ReturnProp = Prop;
     }
     else
     {
         //FillParam here            
     }
 }
 
 Obj->ProcessEvent(Func, FuncParam.GetStructMemory());
```

But… I don’t know how to `//Fillparam here`.

How can I fill the `FuncParam` with the parameters that I need to pass?